# How to compare UTF-8 data against the same data saved in a Latin1 MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8

I have the tedious task of converting a MySQL table which contains data in a Latin1 encoding.

```
CREATE TABLE q_data (
    q_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    label varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    text text NOT NULL,
    points decimal(8,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
    date_updated timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    KEY q_id (q_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
```

This is the `ALTER TABLE` command which I have executed on my table.

```
SET NAMES utf8;
ALTER TABLE q_data change text text blob;
ALTER TABLE q_data CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8, change text text text;
```

Now I need to verify if all my data is converted correctly.
So I tried writing a small Perl code to fetch the data and compare it. But I am getting mismatch error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin;
use lib File::Spec->catdir( $FindBin::RealBin, File::Spec->updir, 'lib' );
use DBI qw(:utils);

# DB Handle for the new DB where I have altered the table
my $dbh_utf8 = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=data;host=xx-dev-1.xxxxx.com;port=3209","aaaa","xxxxxxx",{PrintError => 1, mysql_enable_utf8 => 1 }) || die "fail connecting to db_from";

# DB Handle for the OLD DB
my $dbh_latin = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=data;host=xx-dev-1.xxxxx.com;port=3214","aaaa","xxxxxxx",{PrintError => 1, RaiseError=> 0 }) || die "fail connecting to db_to";

# Fetching the rows which has UTF-8 Characters 
my $sql = qq|SELECT *
 FROM  q_data
 WHERE length(text) <> char_length(text) 
 ORDER BY q_id desc
 LIMIT 10000|;

# Fetching the original data from the old DB in the UTF8 Format
my $sql1 = qq|SELECT q.*, CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(q.text USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8) AS text FROM q_data q WHERE q_id=? and label=?|;`

my $sth = $dbh_utf8->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;`

while( my $data = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    my $latin_data = $dbh_latin->selectrow_hashref($sql1, undef, $data->{q_id}, $data->{label});
    print $latin_data->{text}, "\n";
    if (not defined $latin_data ) {
        #print $data->{q_id}, "\t", "No Latin Data", "\n";
    }
    elsif ( $latin_data->{text} ne $data->{text} ) {
         print $data->{q_id}, "\t", $data->{label}, "\n", "\n", $latin_data->{text}, "\n", $data->{text}, "\n";
    }
}
$sth->finish;
$dbh_utf8->disconnect;
$dbh_latin->disconnect;
```

I have this kind of data in the `q_data` table

```
INSERT INTO q_data (q_id, label, text, points, date_updated)
VALUES('1880941','o14-l1','Clearly states classroom diversity Ã¢Â€Â“ noting considerations for modalities of learning, exceptional students and students with special needs.','0.000','2015-12-03 09:50:57');
```

According to my assumption, I should not get any mismatched data. Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there any other way to verify this? Perhaps in MySQL itself?

Here is the output which is printed when I run this script:

```
1889941 o14-l2

Clearly states classroom diversity â?? noting considerations for only one of the following: modalities of learning, exceptional students and students with special needs.

Clearly states classroom diversity â noting considerations for only one of the following: modalities of learning, exceptional students and students with special needs.
```

Comment: Print out the contents of the first couple of data items that are not matching and look at them.  Make sure you put something around it so you can see whitespace.  Then add this sample data to your question if you don't see the answer just by looking at it.  We can't answer this without the data.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that your data has been corrupted through double encoding.  Let's work through an example to understand what I mean.

The Unicode character for the dash character '–' ([EN DASH](http://www.mclean.net.nz/ucf/?c=U+2013)) is U+2013.  So in a Perl you could represent the character as `"\x{2013}"`.  However in UTF-8, that character is represented as three bytes: E2 80 93.  Which we can see with a hex dump utility:

```
~$ perl -CO -E 'say "\x{2013}"' | xxd
0000000: e280 930a                                ....
```

So it's three bytes which together represent a single character.

Now let's imagine, some process reads in those three bytes but doesn't decode the UTF-8.  Instead, the process interprets each byte as a Latin-1 character:

- E2 in Latin-1 is â (SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX)
- 80 in Latin-1 is an unprintable control character (PADDING CHARACTER)
- 93 in Latin-1 is an unprintable control character (SET TRANSMIT STATE)

Now those three characters are obviously gibberish, but bear with me.  Let's say we encode each of those characters in UTF8:

- U+00E2 becomes C3 A2
- U+0080 becomes C2 80
- U+0093 becomes C2 93

So one character "–" has becomes 6 bytes: C3 A2 C2 80 C2 93

Now if we make the same mistake again, and read those 6 bytes without decoding the UTF-8 to 3 characters, instead we end up with 6 Latin-1 characters. This time instead of using real Latin-1 we'll use Win-Latin-1 (CP1252) to interpret each byte the difference is that the unprintable control characters are replaced with printable characters like smart quotes:

- C3 is Ã
- A2 is ¢
- C2 is Â
- 80 is €
- C2 is Â
- 93 is “

Those six characters together are: Ã¢Â€Â“ – which you may recognise from your sample data.

So in summary somewhere along the line it looks like you've taken a string of UTF-8 bytes and not decoded that into a Perl character string (it should happen automatically when mysql_enable_utf8 is enabled on the DBI connection). Then you've converted something which was already UTF-8 into UTF-8 but in the process corrupted the data.  Whether that was then repeated of whether pasting in here gave the second level of corruption is unclear.

Unwinding double encoding is probably best avoided - go back to the original source data and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The **2-step ALTER** should be used only when you

- wrote utf8 bytes
- with `SET NAMES latin1` in effect
- to a `CHARACTER SET latin1` column.

**Comparing** - Since `SET NAMES` (or equivalent) controls the conversion between the client and the server (and specifies the encoding for the client), you can read both tables (one utf8, one latin1) with the same `SET NAMES` and expect to get the *same* bytes/characters in the client.  At that point, virtually any *client* "==" will do the test you need for comparing.

Comparing in the client is possibly 'safer', on the assumption that the client's view of the text is what you really need to check.

Checking in SQL probably involves `CONVERT( ... USING ...)`, but I hesitate to say without testing.

**Checking data**

To see what is *really* stored, do something like

```
SELECT col, hex(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

latin1 encodings will be 1 byte (2 hex characters); utf8 encodings (for at least Western European accented characters) will be 2 bytes (4 hex).  If you bet 4 bytes (8 hex), you have a different situation - "double encoding".